# How to send TimerTask response to Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, timertask

I  have configured Servlet with TimerTask as shown below

```
package com.scheduler;
public class SchedulerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        long interval = Long.parseLong(config.getInitParameter("interval")) * 60 * 1000;

        MyAction action = new MyAction();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(action, new Date(), interval);
    }

}



package com.scheduler;

    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class MyAction extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Run method called.......");
        }

    }
```

Instead of using System.out.println and printing it on to the console 
Is there anyway can we send this to the servlet ?

Comment: Can you not make your MyAction class have a constructor that takes in an instance of your Servlet class and then call whatever method you want in your servlet class? i.e. servletClass.method()?

Comment: I could not able to follow you , could you please elobrate

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this that you are after?

```
public class SchedulerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        long interval = Long.parseLong(config.getInitParameter("interval")) * 60 * 1000;

        MyAction action = new MyAction(this);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(action, new Date(), interval);
    }

    public void updateSomething(Object obj) {
        //This gets called from your timertask

    }

}



    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class MyAction extends TimerTask {

        SchedulerServlet servlet;

        public MyAction(SchedulerServlet servlet) {
            this.servlet = servlet;
        }

        public void run() {
            //Do something here...
            //Send something back to your servlet class
            this.servlet.updateSomething(obj)
        }

    }
```